# Split IPv4 address into 4 numbers in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

I'm trying to split a given IPv4 address into four numbers.

In SQL Server this query works well for me:

```
select CAST (PARSENAME('10.20.30.40',4) AS INT)
```

result: `10`

```
select CAST (PARSENAME('10.20.30.40',3) AS INT)
```

result: `20`

and so on.

I need the equivalent syntax in Oracle SQL, but can't find it. Any idea?

Comment: There may be something of value in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696008/spliting-string-using-sql-statement-ip-address/29700809#29700809) answer. While it is written for SQL Server, it avoids `ParseName` and provides conversions between `VarChar(n)` and `BigInt`.

Comment: Why do you insist on using Vintage IP?

Comment: Common note for all answers: You proposal using `PARSENAME` works only with four (or less) elements, i.e. IPv4. All given answers you could easily modify to support IPv6, if required.

Comment: To the people downvoting the question: It would help if you would explain what you are objecting to. The question seems pretty clear, the OP showed what he knows about solving it (solution in another SQL dialect) and is asking for the Oracle equivalent. What is missing, or wrong, or unclear, about the question? Why the downvotes? Explain your downvotes if you want them to be helpful to others.

Comment: @MartinSchröder - The OP is not insisting on using Vintage IP (I don't think). The OP needs to process EXISTING data. Are you asking why data which was perhaps stored ten years ago does not use newer kinds of addresses?

Comment: @Eithan if this is a new solution for a new system, then this might not be the smartest idea. In such case I'd really recommend taking care of IPv6 as well.

Answer (score 12):

You could use `regexp_substr`:

```
select ip,
       regexp_substr(ip, '\d+',1,1) as first_octet,
       regexp_substr(ip, '\d+',1,2) as second_octet,
       regexp_substr(ip, '\d+',1,3) as third_octet,
       regexp_substr(ip, '\d+',1,4) as fourth_octet
from  (select '10.20.30.40' AS ip from dual )ips;
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/WOFXQN31182)**

Answer (score 4):

You can use simple string functions (`INSTR` and `SUBSTR`) that are much faster than regular expressions:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/54ebe/5)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE sample_data ( ip_address ) AS
SELECT '10.20.30.40' FROM DUAL
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(
         SUBSTR( ip_address, 1, first_sep - 1 )
       ) AS ClassA,
       TO_NUMBER(
         SUBSTR( ip_address, first_sep + 1, second_sep - first_sep )
       ) AS ClassB,
       TO_NUMBER(
         SUBSTR( ip_address, second_sep + 1, third_sep - second_sep )
       ) AS ClassC,
       TO_NUMBER(
         SUBSTR( ip_address, third_sep + 1 )
       ) AS ClassD
FROM   (
  SELECT ip_address,
         INSTR( ip_address, '.', 1, 1 ) AS first_sep,
         INSTR( ip_address, '.', 1, 2 ) AS second_sep,
         INSTR( ip_address, '.', 1, 3 ) AS third_sep
  FROM   sample_data
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/54ebe/5/0)**:

```
| CLASSA | CLASSB | CLASSC | CLASSD |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|
|     10 |     20 |     30 |     40 |
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you need all in one function, this is another solution:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('10.20.30.40', '\d+', 1, LEVEL) as octet, level
FROM dual 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4;


OCTET   LEVEL
10      1
20      2
30      3
40      4
```

Comment: Still not "all-in-one" enough, since you are hard-coding 4. Best to replace that with 1 + count of dots.