# Creating a SQL Server UDDT for an IP Address?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to create a user-defined data type called IPv4 to store IP addresses.  It seems straightforward enough in concept but the implementation is hard to figure out.

I tried:

```
create type IPv4 from varchar(15);
go

create rule IPv4_Rule
as 
        (CONVERT(tinyint, PARSENAME(@Address, 4)) > -1)
    and (CONVERT(tinyint, PARSENAME(@Address, 3)) > -1)
    and (CONVERT(tinyint, PARSENAME(@Address, 2)) > -1)
    and (CONVERT(tinyint, PARSENAME(@Address, 1)) > -1)
go

exec sp_bindrule 'IPv4_Rule', 'IPv4'
go
```

But this doesn’t work because illegal addresses throw an exception and the rule does not apply.  This is unfortunate because testing for an exception is the easiest way to verify that a value is legal.

I can use very similar code in a stored procedure try/catch block which does work but rules can’t reference other database objects.

A regex would be great but SQL Server doesn’t support them.

Finally, MS says
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/unique-constraints-and-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15

> This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL
> Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to
> modify applications that currently use this feature. We recommend that
> you use check constraints instead. Check constraints are created by
> using the CHECK keyword of CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE. For more
> information, see Unique Constraints and Check Constraints.

I don't believe a check constraint can be bound to a type.

All of this is bringing me to the believe that UDDTs are an under-developed or crippled feature which are useless in all but the most trivial cases.  If so, it is too bad because it seems like a feature with a lot of promise.

Note, I considered using a CLR type but am concerned about it being slow for real-time queries.

Am I missing something?  Is there a better approach.

Comment: Not directly answer your question but If you know C# you can write your own REGEX in SQL using CLR functions (C# code you import into SQL).

Comment: I have done that and use it in another database where I can persist the results.  Real-time queries that join on regex matches are painfully slow.

Comment: You're not wrong -- UDDTs are more or less pointless in terms of type safety and flexibility. CLR types are not, but they're harder to use. Speed is not usually a problem, though. As a compromise, you could store an IPv4 address as an `int` and use CLR methods to process them rather than your own custom type (but I'd start with T-SQL and/or client code for that as well, in case translating to/from string representation isn't that common). In terms of storage this is much friendlier than dot-separated addresses in character form anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have to track a lot of networks so I'm storing the address as both varchar(15) for input/output and binary(4) to perform the math.  I have functions to convert between each.  The UDDT was only to provide type safety which can be moved out to the interface.  If you want to post the response, I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: You might find something useful in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29700809/92546) answer showing how to convert an IPV4 address to/from a `BigInt`.

Comment: To avoid the convert errors you could try using [TRY_CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql). When converting to `tinyint` this has the nice property of returning null for non-numeric strings and strings whose numeric value is outside the range of 0-255. It does, however, return 0 for an empty string which is a fly in its ointment. I'm not sure a rule like this is useful, though, because it doesn't fail for oddities such as `1.2.3.4.FooBar`.

Answer (score 0):

If you specifically need a UDDT AND particularly like ugly things...

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.IPADDR AS TABLE   
(   full_address    VARCHAR(15), 
    network_part_1  AS CONVERT(INT, LEFT(full_address, CHARINDEX('.', full_address)-1)) PERSISTED CHECK (network_part_1 > -1),
    network_part_2  AS CONVERT(INT, LEFT(RIGHT(full_address, LEN(full_address) - CHARINDEX('.', full_address)), CHARINDEX('.', RIGHT(full_address, LEN(full_address) - CHARINDEX('.', full_address)))-1)) PERSISTED CHECK (network_part_2 > -1),
    host_part_1     AS CONVERT(INT, LEFT(RIGHT(RIGHT(full_address, LEN(full_address) - CHARINDEX('.', full_address)), LEN(RIGHT(full_address, LEN(full_address) - CHARINDEX('.', full_address))) - CHARINDEX('.', RIGHT(full_address, LEN(full_address) - CHARINDEX('.', full_address)))), CHARINDEX('.', RIGHT(RIGHT(full_address, LEN(full_address) - CHARINDEX('.', full_address)), LEN(RIGHT(full_address, LEN(full_address) - CHARINDEX('.', full_address))) - CHARINDEX('.', RIGHT(full_address, LEN(full_address) - CHARINDEX('.', full_address)))))-1)) PERSISTED CHECK (host_part_1 > -1),
    host_part_2     AS CONVERT(INT, REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(full_address), CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(full_address))-1))) PERSISTED CHECK (host_part_2 > -1)
);
```

On the upside, if it works for you, you never have to look at it again.

NOTE: you cant use non-deterministic functions (e.g. PARSENAME() ) in this context, nor UDF's, hence the string manipulation.

But for all the value it provides you may as well use a table valued function instead;

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.split_ip
(   @full_address VARCHAR(15))
RETURNS @t_split_ip TABLE
(   network_part_1 INT,
    network_part_2 INT,
    host_part_1    INT,
    host_part_2    INT)
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @t_split_ip
    SELECT CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(@full_address, 4)),
           CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(@full_address, 3)),
           CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(@full_address, 2)),
           CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(@full_address, 1))
     WHERE CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(@full_address, 4)) > -1
       AND CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(@full_address, 3)) > -1
       AND CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(@full_address, 2)) > -1
       AND CONVERT(INT, PARSENAME(@full_address, 1)) > -1
    
    RETURN
END
```

For example;

```
DECLARE @ip_address IPADDR
DECLARE @sample_ip VARCHAR(15) = '192.168.1.12'

INSERT INTO @ip_address VALUES(@sample_ip)
SELECT * FROM @ip_address

SELECT * FROM dbo.split_ip(@sample_ip)
```

I have made everything INT datatype to handle the validation part of your query, If you use TINYINT you dont really need the validation because TINYINT is positive anyway. You will get an overflow type error instead I think.